# SSL not being served for AppEngine custom (sub)domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, google-apps

I am migrating a site over to google appengine and am having trouble getting it working with SSL on a custom domain (www.example.com)

Since the site was already having its email hosted via google apps, I did not get the same wizards that one would see when creating a new site. Also, it was created with the free tier of google apps if that makes a difference.

Things I have done:

1. Authorized the appengine project on google apps
2. Enabled SSL billing (and tested that changing the daily quota affects VPI ability- they are synced)
3. Added SNI slot and created a self-signed certificate (for testing and ultimately CloudFlare) for www.example.com
4. Set to serve SNI
5. In apps - added www.example.com for custom domain for appengine project
6. In appengine- added www.example.com for settings/custom domain (note- under the "SSL Support" header here- it says "none" and there is no way to change it. which makes sense since, I think this is never actually used and apps will bypass appengine for ssl requests?)

With these settings- http://www.example.com works, however https://www.example.com does not connect at all (i.e. not an issue of invalid cert)

Note that in the appengine settings on the apps page, it says that I can access the project via https://www.example.com and https://project-name.appspot.com

In case it's relevant, I am now hosting the DNS on Cloudflare and I turn it off/on or flexible/full for testing (to minimize downtime, since clients expect to only connect to https://). Assume for the above it was simply turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK- it seems that for a self-signed certificate it is necessary to use a key in a format that wasn't working with default "how to self sign" searches :) here's what I ended up doing that worked:

1. openssl genrsa -out rsa_private_key.key 2048
2. openssl req -new -key rsa_private_key.key -out request.csr
3. openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in request.csr -signkey rsa_private_key.key -out yourdomain.com.crt
4. openssl rsa -in rsa_private_key.key -text > myserver.key.pem

Then upload the yourdomain.com.csr and myserver.key.pem

Comment: Great, the GAE tutorial didn't work, but your post worked with a paid certificate as well. I just replaced step 3. with the certificate provided by the CA.

Comment: I'm curious, in your working setup, what does it say under the "SSL Support" header in the appengine custom domain console? (Still "none", or did it change to something else?)

Comment: Google Cloud Console has totally changed - it is now under App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains / SSL Certificates. Let's you add a custom domain and upload ssl certificates